# What is causing my cursor to look so strange?

Tags: terminal, cursor

Whenever I hit the end or beginning of a line, I get this very odd character where my cursor was. Any idea what may be causing this? I believe I have my fonts and theme correctly installed. I'm using Debian with the default xfce terminal.

[image: gif video of the cursor error]

Comment: It says `001b`, which is the escape character. There is something in your vimrc file that does this (either something you added yourself, or a plugin). See: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: I have the same problem on the ROXTerm emulator but not on the XTerm. (On ArchLinux.) Haven't tried to fix the former since the latter works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is your font, encoding or both that are at work. It's very hard to tell exacly what the cause is, but i recommend you reinstall font or check if you have the same problem with another font.